# Query regarding equality operator(compatible operands) in JAVA

Tags: java, equality-operator

I am new to JAVA and was going through the equality operator. After trying several combinations of operands, I am a bit confused as to what exactly is the definition of compatible operands for equality operator(==) in Java.

```
int x = 23;
if (x == 23.3f) {   // compiler accepts it. (may be because both are primitives)

int x = 23;     
Double d = new Double(23.3); 
if (x == d) {    // compiler accepts it. (may be compatible pair of primitive and object reference)

int x = 23;
String s = "hello";
if (x == s)   // compiler throws error  - incompatible operands for == operator.
```

So, it looks to me, there should be some formal definition of compatible operands for equality operator. Please help me in clarifying this doubt.

Comment: for string there is `.equals` method. and in your last `if` it is clearly that they are incompatible because you are tryong to compare an Object(String) to a primitive type(int,long,double ...)

Comment: I understand that .equals is there, but my query is specifically regarding ==. if you see my 2nd example, i am comparing primitive with Object(Double.) and compiler accepts it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Compiler accepts it, because `x` and `23.3f` have primitive numeric types. And comparison will return `false`.
2. Compiler accepts it, because java [unboxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) `Double` object to `double` primitive upon comparison.
3. Compiler cannot accept it, because `x` is a primitive numeric type, and `s` is reference to a `String` class instance. It is not possible to comparison number primitive and reference to object.

Comment: Regarding #2, Unboxing always happens when your other operand is primitive?

Comment: according to the official definition: `Autoboxing (and unboxing) is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes.` primitive type and corresponsing object wrapper classes examples: `int` and `Integer`, `double` and `Double`, etc. In comparison if one operand is a wrapper class instance and other operand is a primitive type, then unboxing happens. Moreover, if both operands are wrapper class instances, i.e Integer, then java compares values of these objects, not references.

Comment: To compare `Double` and/or `double` values do not use `==` operator. use `java.lang.Double.compare()` method. It because of precision issues. Check this link for example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/double_compare.htm

Comment: I too recommend you avoid no. 2. I for my part can never remember whether it boxes the primitive or unboxes the object, and the result would not be the same in the two cases. So for readability, make the unboxing explicit if this is what you intended, as in `x == d.doubleValue()` (I also agree in warning against comparing double values with `==`, though).

Answer (score 1):

For

```
int x = 23;
if (x == 23.3f)
```

If you look at the byte code using `javap -v`, the `int` will be converted to a `float`. i.e, `i2f` will be called and then they will be compared as 2 float values using `fcmpl`.

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   Stack=2, Locals=2, Args_size=1
   0:   bipush  23
   2:   istore_1
   3:   iload_1
   4:   i2f       // The line of interest. Converts int to float.
   5:   ldc     #16; //float 23.3f
   7:   fcmpl     // compare two floats
   8:   ifne    11
   11:  return
```

In third case, you are comparing a primitive with an Object (String), which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are objects.
 The `==` compares objects by reference, not by their internal value.
All others`(int, double)` are compared in `==` by there object references so in case of string it doesnt match so for string we must u `.equals` operator also java is case sensitive so while comparing string u must take care of `Case's of strings`

Answer (score 0):

The equality operator implies some restrictions and transformations, the rules are rather large and are described in the language specification https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21

1. So in first case "x" promoted to float type before comparison.
2. In the second "d" unboxed and "x" promoted to double type before comparison.
3. In third compile-time error occurs because String is incompatible with primitive type. String can be compared with the same type or types from which it is inherited.

The compile-time error also could occurs because the class types are unrelated (that is, they are not the same, and neither is a subclass of the other), so a cast between them will always fail.
Regarding the comparison of the type with some interface type, the compiler allows any comparison, except then one variable can never reference a value that implements the interface, this is because type is a final type, and a variable of a final type always holds a value of the same run-time type as its compile-time type. Therefore, the run-time type of variable must be exactly the type which does not implement specified interface.